# names of different http schemes

Tags: http, url, www, naming

I am wondering what the different names are for these things:

```
localhost                  (host?)
localhost:3000             (address?)
http://localhost:3000      (url base?)
http://localhost:3000/xyz  (url resource?)
```

what are the best names for the different entities above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### what are the best names for the different entities?

> ```
>          userinfo       host      port
>           ┌──┴───┐ ┌──────┴──────┐ ┌┴┐
>   https://john.doe@www.example.com:123/forum/questions/?tag=networking&order=newest#top
>   └─┬─┘   └───────────┬──────────────┘└───────┬───────┘ └───────────┬─────────────┘ └┬┘
>   scheme          authority                  path                 query           fragment
> ```

Source [Uniform Resource Identifier - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier)

The above diagram shows the names for all of the parts of a URI (where the scheme is `HTTP` or `HTTPS`).

Comment: thanks, so what is Host+Port? I am calling it an "address"...and what about scheme+host+port? I guess I will call it "full address"?

Comment: host+port is authority (as userinfo is optional).